# Action of fermion fields on fermionic states

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fermions

I was asked to show that if $c^\dagger_r(p) |0 \rangle = |p,r\rangle$ is a massive vector particle state with momentum $p$ and polarisation $\epsilon^\mu_r(p)$ then

$$\langle 0 \lvert A^\mu(x) \lvert p,r\rangle = \epsilon^\mu_r(p) e^{-ip\cdot x}$$

Then the next part of the question asks:

> Deduce  similar  expressions  for  the  action  of  a  Dirac  field  and  its  adjoint  on  fermion and anti-fermion states, using the mode expansions and anticommutation relations for fermions

The mode expansion for a fermionic field is given by:
$$\psi(x) = \sum_s \int d\tilde{q} \left(a_s(q) u(q,s) e^{-iq \cdot x}+ b_s^\dagger(q) v(q,s) e^{iq \cdot x}\right)$$
What I did was the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_s \int d\tilde{q} \left(a_s(q) u(q,s) e^{-iq \cdot x}+ b_s^\dagger(q) v(q,s) e^{iq \cdot x}\right)|p,r\rangle = \\
\sum_s \int d\tilde{q} u(q,s) e^{-iq \cdot x} a_s(q) a^\dagger_r(p)|0\rangle + \sum_s \int d\tilde{q} v(q,s) e^{iq \cdot x} b_s^\dagger(q) b_r^\dagger(p) |0\rangle \\=
\sum_s \int d\tilde{q} u(q,s) e^{-iq \cdot x} \left( \delta_{rs} \delta(q-p) - a_r^\dagger(p)a_s(q)\right)|0\rangle + \\
\sum_s \int d\tilde{q} v(q,s) e^{iq \cdot x} b_s^\dagger(q) b_r^\dagger(p) |0\rangle
\end{align*}$$

In the first the integral and the sum vanish because the kronecker delta and the delta function pick out a specific value of q and s.

Then taking multiplying from the left by $\langle 0 |$ we get:

$$u(p,s)e^{-ip\cdot x} \langle 0 | 0 \rangle + 0 = u(p,s)e^{-ip\cdot x}$$

where for the first term I've used the fact an annihilation operators gives zero acting on the vacuum and for the second term I've used the fact that:

$$\left(\langle 0 |b_s(q)\right)^\dagger = 0$$

Is this the correct way of proceeding? One thing I'm unsure is what I did for the writing of the state $|p,r\rangle$ is correct, because as you can see I "created" the state using two different operators in the same line: $a_r^\dagger(p,r) |0 \rangle$ and $b_r^\dagger(p,r) |0 \rangle$.

Comment: It is correct. The only mistake I see is that instead of $b_r^\dagger(p)$ you should have $a_r^\dagger(p)$ everywhere since the original state is defined by $| p , r \rangle = a_r^\dagger(p) | 0 \rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state $| p,r \rangle$ is a wrong notation for such a state. Indeed one has to specify if it is a "fermion" or an "anti-fermion". You should write once for all at the beginning $| p,r \rangle=a^\dagger(p,r)|0\rangle$ or $| p,r \rangle=b^\dagger(p,r)|0\rangle$, but don't mix them. For the following, you can follow my previous answer here: [A question on Proca equation and real massive vector fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/633569/a-question-on-proca-equation-and-real-massive-vector-fields/633680#633680)

Comment: Ok, so my procedure is correct though?

Comment: You have the correct approach, for me. The key for this type of calculation is indeed the commutation relations of the ladder operators.